# PyCharm and integrating with Java

Tags: java, import, jython, pycharm

This question is probably ridiculous, because i have very small experience with python.
But have to work with that these days.

Problem is that IDE cannot resolve any reference to `java.*` packages and to others in my own libraries.

I did add some paths to the necessary libraries in interpeter but nothing changed.

Does i did something wrong or do i need any third-party plugin?

I am using PyCharm 2.5b with Jython 2.5.3 as interpreter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PyCharm Java support is [very limited](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2012/01/the-story-behind-jython-support-in-pycharm/), it cannot parse jars and understand Java imports right now.

If you want to develop with Java and Python at the same time, consider using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with Python plug-in.

Adding `jre/lib/rt.jar` to the Jython classpath will get the imports resolved and code completion available:

[image: rt.jar]

[image: completion]

Note that you will need to disable **Trying to call a non-callable object** inspection because of the [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4269).

Comment: Yes, nice solution and guide. Exactly what i was looking for. Спасибо)

Comment: How can you add code completion for Jython in Pycharm 5? It doesn't seem to be possible to add settings like the above screenshots.